# Only build projects if something has changed

Tags: node.js, git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We want to split up our project into smaller pieces. Our current CI process goes through a short test phase and then runs a deployment script. However, if nothing has changed in one of the sub project, we do not want to go through the build for this.

Jenkins without pipelines supports exclusions in the SCM configuration (we use git) and based on this, you can configure a specific job to run. However, when using a pipeline, how can I know, if I should build this part or not? How do I get access to the paths that were affected by the last push?

At the moment our script is very simple, and we would like to keep it as simple as possible.

We were playing around with the [scripted](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#scripted-pipeline) and the [declarative](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-pipeline) syntax, but could not find a good solution.

Declarative:

```
#!groovy​
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        nodejs '8.1'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                checkout scm
            }
        }

        # Only continue, if something has changed

        stage('Install') {
            steps {
                sh 'npm install'
            }
        }

        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'npm run test-jenkins'
            }
            post {
                always {
                    junit "artifacts/test/report.xml"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Scripted:

```
#!groovy​
node {
    def nodejs = tool name: '8.1', type: 'jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation'
    env.PATH = "${nodejs}/bin:${env.PATH}"

    stage('Checkout') {
        checkout scm
    }

    # Only continue, if something has changed


    stage('Install') {
        sh 'npm install'
    }

    stage('Test') {
        try {
            sh 'npm run test-jenkins'
        } finally {
            junit "artifacts/test/report.xml"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After the build is done, make a tag to the current commit. In the next build, compare the new commit and the tag. Continue if only they are not the same commit (or tree if you care about only the file contents). And after the new build is done, reset the tag from the previous commit to the current commit.

Comment: @ElpieKay This worked! Thank you very much. I'll write it up and post it as an answer.

Comment: It's all right. Glad it helps. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [ElpieKay's fast comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44818701/only-build-projects-if-something-has-changed#comment76617750_44818701) on my question, we now have an elegant solution:

1. Make a tag to the current commit on a successful build
2. In the next build compare the new commit and the tag for changes

We are using a [multi-branch pipeline](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Multibranch+Plugin) and a parallel build for the multiple projects we have under the same source root. We iterate through the projects (`serviceX`) and check in the corresponding directory for a change:

```
def projects = ['service1', 'service2']
def builders = [:]
for (p in projects) {
    def label = p

    builders[label] = {
        def tag = "${BRANCH_NAME}_last"
        node {
            echo "Checking for changes compared to ${tag} in directory ${label}"
            try {
                sh "./check-for-changes ${tag} ${label}"
            } catch (ignored) {
                echo "Nothing to do"
                return
            }
            dir (label) {
                stage(label + ": Install") {
                    sh "npm install"
                }

                stage(label + ": Test") {
                    try {
                        sh "npm run test-jenkins"
                    } finally {
                        junit 'artifacts/test/report.xml'
                    }
                }

                echo "Setting tag for the last build on this branch"
                sh "git tag -f ${tag}"
            }
        }
    }
}

parallel builders
```

... and the script to check for changes:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
SHA_PREV=$1
if [ -z ${SHA_PREV} ]; then
    echo "Usage: `basename $0` <tag> <path>"
    exit 1
fi

CHECK_PATH=$2
if [ -z ${CHECK_PATH} ]; then
    echo "Usage: `basename $0` <tag> <path>"
    exit 1
fi

if `git rev-parse ${SHA_PREV} >/dev/null 2>&1`; then
    echo "Found previous tag: ${SHA_PREV}"
else
    SHA_PREV=`git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD`
    echo "Using initial commit: ${SHA_PREV}"
fi

changes=`git diff --name-only ${SHA_PREV} HEAD | grep ${CHECK_PATH}/`
if [ ! -n "${changes}" ]; then
    echo "No changes found"
    exit 2 # no changes found
fi
```